# Count number of unique values for multiple columns in Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, numpy, apply

How to count a number of unique values in multiple columns in Python, pandas etc. I can do for one column using "nunique" function. I need something like:

```
print("Number of unique values in Var1", DF.var1.nunique(),sep="= ").
```

For all the variables in the dataset. Something like a loop or apply function maybe. I tried a lot of things failed to get what I desired.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you tried things, show us what you tried. :)

Comment: Use apply like `df.apply(pd.Series.nunique)`

Comment: @Dark, a bit simplified version: `df.agg('nunique')`

Comment: @Maxu we might be overthinking its just `df.nunique()`

Comment: @Dark, yeah, I didn't notice - it was added in Pandas 0.20.0

Comment: Thanks. All of them worked. I guess I was overthinking it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to `print` number of unique values per column, so use:

```
for k, v in df.nunique().to_dict().items():
    print('{}={}'.format(k,v))
```